# Can I define the same function with two names?

Tags: php

I want to define one function, but with two different names. I can achieve that such:

```
function my1($a, $b) { ......  }
function my2($a, $b) { my1($a,$b); }
```

but I am interested, if there is a shorter way, like:

```
function my1 & my2 ($a, $b) { ......  }
```

Comment: I am just curious why so ?? Why you need to define one function twice ??

Comment: Can you tell us your need to do like this ?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @TTodua, with so much experience in SO, it will be helpful for the users who are trying to help you by responding to them

Comment: @mainan, do you know that in most questions i get the most inappropriate anti-question : "why do you need that"... as I ask, that means i need that.

Comment: First thing one learn about understanding one's need : asking "why do you need that, what are you trying to do". I am always amazed by the power of this question... "why ?". Even if your are the best in your field (maybe especially if you are), you shouldn't probably answer by "because I need it". Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try anonymous functions. It allows you to call the same function but with different names. like so

```
<?php
$function_1 = $function_2 = function($a,$b){ //The anonymous function is assigned names $function_1 & $function_2.
    echo $a.' - '.$b;
};

$function_1('a','b');

$function_2('1','2');
?>
```

Read the complete reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a recursive function instead of creating two same function. For example:

```
function my1($a, $b, $is_recursive = false) {
    ...

    if ($is_recursive) {
        my1($a, $b, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! for that you need to use anonymous functions.
One variable hold your function and another variable refer to same variable.

```
<?php
// Define function
$say_hello_1 = function ()
{
  echo "Hello";
};

// Refer to same function with different name
$say_hello_2 = $say_hello_1;

// Call to both of them
$say_hello_2();
$say_hello_1();
```

Both of call represent same function and print Hello twice.

Comment: Answer was posted at a same time when i was writing!